# git push origin master , invalid port number

Tags: git, push

when i do

> git push origin master

i get an alert message "invalid port number" and on the console i can see
"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Please could someone help me what i am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It depends the nature of "origin" repo.

For GitHub, for instance, you [need a `git@github.com:` URL to be able to push](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/1683-git-push-fails-with-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

> My ssh works as expected, and I can push to acts_as_eav no problems.
>
> Any idea whats causing this?

```
rasheed@rashbuntu:~/deprec$ git push -v
Pushing to git://github.com/visfleet/deprec.git
Looking up github.com ... done.
Connecting to github.com (port 9418) ... 207.97.227.239 done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

> It seems my git repo ended up with the wrong url

```
git://github.com/visfleet/deprec.git
```

> vs

```
git@github.com:visfleet/deprec.git
```